# The right place to make calls to an API from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a view in Laravel that is responsible for displaying different data that are received from different calls to the Twitter API. This is the code:

TwitterRepository:

```
 public function getTwitterList($type, $count)
    {
        list($user, $settings) = $this->twitterConfig();

        $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/'.$type.'/list.json';
        $getfield = '?screen_name=' . $user . '&count=' . $count;
        $requestMethod = 'GET';
        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $follow_count = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
            ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
            ->performRequest();

        $get_count = json_decode($follow_count, true);

        return $get_count;
    }
... // Some similar methods
```

TwitterController:

```
public function index()
    {
        $twitterConfig = $this->twitterRepository->getTwitterData();

        $twitterFollowers = $twitterConfig['followers_count'];
        $twitterFollowing = $twitterConfig['friends_count'];
        $twitterCountTweet = $twitterConfig['statuses_count'];
        $twitterProfileDescription = $twitterConfig['description'];
        $twitterProfileImage = $twitterConfig['followers_count'];

        $lastTweets = $this->twitterRepository->getLastTweets();

        $twitterFollowingJson = $this->twitterRepository->getTwitterList('friends', 15);
        $twitterFollowingList = $twitterFollowingJson['users'];

        $twitterFollowersJson = $this->twitterRepository->getTwitterList('followers', 15);
        $twitterFollowersList = $twitterFollowersJson['users'];

        return view('admin.twitter-index', compact('twitterFollowers', 'twitterFollowing', 'twitterCountTweet',
            'twitterProfileDescription', 'twitterProfileImage', 'lastTweets', 'twitterFollowingList', 'twitterFollowersList'));
    }
```

The problem is that for every call I add to get other information in the same view (like lists of people), logically increases the response time of the page more and more. Could you help me improve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can load the view with some important api calls and rest of the api call you can make in view,  you can make some api call via JQuery and show loading gif /text to that particular part of view.

Comment: You can shift some of the calls to trigger after the view is loaded using ajax like @Vikash suggested. Also possibly limit the volumes for the API call (e.g. get 10 tweets per request with a show more button. If the user wants to see more, he clicks the button or use unlimited scrolling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real way reduce response time for the user here is to make the API  calls asynchronously from the browser, rather than having your server make them.

Consider building your view so that when it loads it shows "loading feedback" to the user and then makes the API calls via AJAX with each section showing content as each API call completes.